# Resource characteristic and territory management in Field Service of Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

Can anybody help me to understand the characteristic and territory mapping and the filter of resource while creating a booking in Field service of Dynamics 365?